# Maximization linear system with three variables

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, maximization

Maximize `C= 528r + 492s + 348w`subject to:

```
1) r + s + w ≥ 12
2) r ≤  4 --> r + 0 + 0 ≤  4
3) w ≥ 3s --> 0 – 3s + 1w ≥0
```

I can't find any code examples online where I can maximize using three variables with inequalities. The closest I found was something that looks like this from another question: [Solving linear equations w. three variables using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354807/solving-linear-equations-w-three-variables-using-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2, -4, 4], [34, 3, -1], [1, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([8, 30, 108])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

Comment: look into `scipy.optimize`

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is called a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Therefore you want to look into [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). At the bottom of that page you'll also find an example of how to solve a problem such as yours.